# How to join two datasets based on a dynamic correlationId in Kusto (Azure Data Explorer)?

Tags: azure, devops, azure-data-explorer, kusto-explorer

I have two datasets in Azure Data Explorer: requests and exceptions. I want to join these datasets based on a dynamic correlationId. The correlationId should be generated using the combination of operation_ParentId and operation_Id columns from both datasets.

Here's an example of the query I tried:

```js
requests
| extend correlationId = strcat('c3172da7e4803fc2', '-', operation_Id) 
| join kind=inner (exceptions
                   | extend correlationId = strcat('c3172da7e4803fc2', '-', operation_Id) 
                  ) on correlationId
| project ProcessingDate, OpCo, Cosmos_OrderId, ReasonMessage, data, operation_ParentId, operation_Id, correlationId
| where Cosmos_OrderId contains "1983"
```

The above query works when I use a fixed value as the prefix for correlationId, but when I try to use `correlationId = strcat(operation_ParentId, '-', operation_Id)`, it doesn't return any results.

The issue seems to be that operation_ParentId is the same for both datasets (requests and exceptions), and I cannot use it as a unique identifier. I also tried using the Cosmos_OrderId and OpCo columns, but they are not available in the exceptions dataset.

Is there a way to create a dynamic correlationId that combines operation_ParentId and operation_Id from both datasets and use it to join the datasets effectively? I understand that Cartesian joins can be resource-intensive, so I'm open to exploring other approaches to improve the join efficiency.

How can I achieve this join using Kusto?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried your scenario in my environment and it's working fine for me.

I took 2 sample datasets and able to join those two datasets based on a dynamic correlationId.

**My Code:**

```
let requests= datatable (operation_ParentId:string, operation_Id:string, name_requests:string, nick_name:string)
[
"1224","24","Rakesh","Virat",
"1226","26","Laddu","MS",
"1216","16","Raju","ABD"
];

let exceptions = datatable (operation_ParentId:string, operation_Id:string, name_exceptions:string)
[
"1224","24","Rakesh",
"1226","26","Laddu",
"1216","1","Datta"  
];

requests
| extend correlationId = strcat(operation_ParentId, '-', operation_Id) 
| join kind=inner (exceptions
                   | extend correlationId = strcat(operation_ParentId, '-', operation_Id) 
                  ) on correlationId
|project operation_ParentId, operation_Id, correlationId,name_exceptions,name_requests,nick_name;
```

You can see the inner join of both datasets and the dynamic column as well.

[image]

Recheck the datasets data and make sure the `operation_ParentId` column is a string type. Try to do the same operations by adding some columns (like `operation_ParentId`) and check whether it results the same or not.